# input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label selector does not work with autofill

Tags: css, css-selectors, placeholder, pseudo-class

I have floating placeholder in the input field.

Placeholder will appear in center when we input value has not been provided. as shown in the below screenshot (Email and password is placeholder).

[image]

Now when you provide the value to email it does look like below. Observer the Email and password has been pulled up when value has been provided

[image]

The problem occurs when browser starts auto-filling/autocomplete this value from the saved credentials on page load like username, email, password so on. see the screen shot below:

[image]

**css**

```
:root {
  --input-padding-x: .75rem;
  --input-padding-y: .75rem;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.form-signin {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.form-label-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.form-label-group > input,
.form-label-group > label {
  padding: var(--input-padding-y) var(--input-padding-x);
}

.form-label-group > label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Override default `<label>` margin */
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.form-label-group input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  padding-top: calc(var(--input-padding-y) + var(--input-padding-y) * (2 / 3));
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
}

.form-label-group input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  padding-top: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--input-padding-y) / 3);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-signin">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please Type new password</h1>
    <div class="form-label-group">
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required=""
            autofocus="">
        <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-label-group">
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
            required="">
        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" (click)="onSubmit()" type="button">Change password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I had already tried to autofocus on the email field but that did not worked.
I also tried to click the element from the code after the page load but with no luck. Please help me how do I fix this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It works for me

```
.form-label-group input:-webkit-autofill ~ label {
        /* CSS property  */
}
```

You can try it

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `:-webkit-autofill`, that's just what I was missing!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. In my form, I'm using the following selectors to move my label text out of the way, on any of these 3 conditions:

1. `:focus` (so it's not in the way of the cursor when focused)
2. `:not(:placeholder-shown)` (indicating "the input is not empty")
3. `:-webkit-autofill` (because 2 wasn't triggering on page refresh / autofill)

The SCSS combination is:

```
input {
  &:focus, &:not(:placeholder-shown), &:-webkit-autofill {
    &+label { /* Move your label */ }
  }
}
```

(Note that you also need a `placeholder=" "` on your input.)

Here's a live example: https://codepen.io/jeffward/pen/ZdBxXd

Comment: Works fine in Chrome, not in FF. I couldn't find any alternative.

Comment: Indeed, stupid FireFox. There is a very old, outstanding feature request for `:-moz-autofill` https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740979 Although `:autofill` wouldn't even be necessary if `:placeholder-shown` worked correctly when auto-filled. :P

Answer (score 2):

Add `placeholder=" "` to the input Element.