# Float label over text input when focussed or it contains text

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a search bar that I want to animated so that the Label moves from being over the text input to above it. I found a pretty good example in a fireship.io video, that uses this CSS and html found [here](https://github.com/fireship-io/230-animated-form-password-meter/blob/master/src/Login.svelte)

In that example, I get the behaviour and style I want, with the Label moving above and staying there when text is entered, or moving back down if you don't enter anything, very similar to something found in Material UI

When I try it, I get half the behaviour, I get the label to move when I focus on the text input, but then it moves back, regardless of if I enter Text:
[image: "Default" start, when the page is loaded, and has no text inside it]

[image: Text Entered, but still focussed]

[image: After Text is entered, but not focussed, the Label should stay above]

Here is the specific HTML and CSS I am using, which are inside a React App and a SCSS file that is being "complied" using VSCode's Live SASS Watcher extension:

```
function searchBar() {
    return (
        <div class="SearchBar">
            <input type="text" name="Search" class="input" placeholder=""/>
            <label class="label" for="Search">Search...</label>
      </div>
    )
}



.SearchBar {
    @extend .base;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed var(--text-primary);
    width: 50vw;
    margin: 3vh auto 3vh;
    .input {
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        padding: 1rem;
        background: none;
        color: var(--text-primary);
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 75vw;
    }
    .label {
        color: var(--text-primary);
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        transform-origin: 0%;
        transition: transform 400ms;
    }
}

.SearchBar::after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 50vw;
    background: #1625ff;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: 0%;
    transition: transform 500ms ease;
    top: 2px;
}

.SearchBar:focus-within {
    border-color: transparent;
    .label, .input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .label {
        transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-5rem);    
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different fixes I've found both here on StackOverflow and elsewhere.
The first thing was to use the "required" attribute, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Search" class="input" required/>

.SearchBar:focus-within {
    border-color: transparent;
    .label, .input:valid + .label {
        transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-5rem);    
    }
}
```

This produces the same result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also tried moving the:

```
.label, .input:valid + .label {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-5rem);    
}
```

so that it is outside the ".SearchBar:focus-within" class and psuedo class with both of the above solutions, and I got the same thing.

Next thing was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55427966/inputnotplaceholder-shown-label-selector-does-not-work-with-autofill). and though this is specifically for if something was autofilled, I figured I'd give it a go, and again, SAME result as before...

Another thing I've tried is using "&" instead of nesting the classes like I have above:

```
.SearchBar:focus-within {
    border-color: transparent;
    .input {
        &:focus, &:not(:placeholder-shown) &:-webkit-autofill{
            &+label {
                transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-5rem);
            }
        }    
    }   
}
```

Again once again, this produces EXACTLY the same thing. I'm clearly missing something, but can't seem to pin what it is. I can either get the label to move when focussed or not, like I have now, or have it permanently be above the text input, which is the "final" state I want.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :valid css selector which ensures there's text inside the input and persist the :focus

HTML:

```
<div class="SearchBar">
   <input type="text" name="Search" class="input" required/>
   <label class="label" for="Search">Search</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.SearchBar {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 400px;
}

.label {
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #888;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 1rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform-origin: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 400ms;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.SearchBar {
  .input:valid + .label {
    color: #000;
    transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-4rem) translateX(-0.8rem);
  }
}
```

**Working Example [Here](https://codepen.io/amrdys/pen/RwaEzbK)**